# File download issue in TIdHttp using Delphi

Tags: delphi, indy10, delphi-10-seattle

I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle for developing android mobile application and desktop application. And as per the requirement i need to download the Mp3 file (may be 1 to 5 MB) and need to save the file in the mobile app which is created using Delphi.
And by using IIS, I made the path in public and the file can be accessed any where. And the server system has upload speed as 512 Kbps and Download speed as 1Mbps.
And now I'm trying to download the file file from server to mobile using TIdHttp.

If I'm using my mobile app in the Wifi (Download Speed: 8 Mbps, Upload Speed: 2 Mbps), the file is getting downloaded properly.

But When I'm downloading the file using Mobile data (3g, 
Download Speed: 4 Mbps, Upload Speed: 260 Kbps), the file is not getting downloaded properly and it is showing the exception as 'Read Timeout'. Also I have increased the ReadTimeout to 9999999. Then, also file is not getting downloaded. Also when I have tried to open the link in Google chrome. Then, also file is not playing.

Should I need to increase the Upload speed speed of the system or by changing the code, I can download properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect IIS is not playing nicely here.

Comment: I covered this same question yesterday in the [Embarcadero forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=172219).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After restarting the Server System, I can able to download the file using slow internet also. Thanks every one for your suggestions.**

Answer (score 0):

1. try modern component `THTTPClient` from `System.Net.HttpClient`.
2. can you download your file via web browser? just to be sure, that IIS configured properly.

Comment: 1. Can we use THttpClient in Firemonkey android? Sure I will use this component and test.
2. And if I'm using the speed internet in my mobile, then the file is getting opened in the browser. If I'm using the low speed internet, then the file is not opening in the browser. My Server download speed is 1 Mbps and upload speed is 512 Kbps. Is this causing the issue

Comment: @test12345 -- yes, THTTPClient works fine on Android 4, MacOS 10 and WIn32/64 platform. I guarantee you :)

Comment: @test12345 -- most important -- it doesn't not required OpenSSL library for SSL connection.